# How get specific element from a div with same id and class in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to print "United state" and California in separated lines like

```
Country is : United State
State is : California
```

The problem is each list item has the same class and id so when I loop through the list items it gives United States and California together.

I hope you guys will understand what I'm trying to say.

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs" id="BREADCRUMBS">
  <li class="breadcrumb_item " itemscope="" itemtype="http://data- vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a class="breadcrumb_link" href="/Tourism-g191-United_States-Vacations.html" itemprop="url" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Breadcrumbs', 'click', 'Country', 1, this.href); ">
      <span itemprop="title">United States</span>
    </a>
    <span class="separator">›</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb_item " itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a class="breadcrumb_link" href="/Tourism-g28926-California-Vacations.html" itemprop="url" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Breadcrumbs', 'click', 'State', 2, this.href); ">
      <span itemprop="title">California (CA)</span>
    </a>
    <span class="separator">›</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb_item " itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="breadcrumb_link" href="/Tourism-g32655-Los_Angeles_California-Vacations.html" itemprop="url" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Breadcrumbs', 'click', 'City', 3, this.href); "><span itemprop="title">Los Angeles</span></a><span class="separator">›</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb_item " itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="breadcrumb_link" href="/Restaurants-g32655-Los_Angeles_California.html" itemprop="url" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Breadcrumbs', 'click', '', 4, this.href); return setOneTimeCookie('mcreset','true');"><span itemprop="title">Los Angeles Restaurants</span></a>
    <span class="separator">›</span>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb_item ">Providence</li>
</ul>
```

```
here is my scraping script with python beautifulsoup
```

```js
import sys,io,csv,requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g32655-d594024-Reviews-Providence-Los_Angeles_California.html"
r = requests.get(url)
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
maindiv = soup.find_all("body", {"class": "ltr domn_en_US lang_en globalNav2011_reset hr_tabs_placement_test tabs_below_meta scroll_tabs full_width_page content_blocks css_commerce_buttons flat_buttons sitewide xo_pin_user_review_to_top track_back"})
for div in maindiv:
 divone = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "PAGE"})
 for listitem in divone:
  div12 = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "breadCrumbBackground blue bgwhite "})
  for listitem in div12:
   ulpart = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "breadcrumbs"})
   for unorder in ulpart[0]:
    div2 = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "breadcrumb_item "})
    for listitem in div2:
     tag = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "breadcrumb_link"})
     for spandiv in tag:
      span = soup.find_all("span", {"itemprop": "title"})
      for country_name in span:
       
       print(country_name.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the relevant parts of `onclick` attribute defining what breadcrumb is country and which is state. I would use a partial match via `*=` [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to implement that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""Your HTML"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

country = soup.select_one("li.breadcrumb_item a[onclick*=Country]").get_text(strip=True)
state = soup.select_one("li.breadcrumb_item a[onclick*=State]").get_text(strip=True)

print("The country is: '%s'" % country)
print("The state is: '%s'" % state)
```

Prints:

```
The country is: 'United States'
The state is: 'California (CA)'
```